# All usb ports broken on laptop, no bluetooth what to do?

Tags: laptop, usb

All the usb ports(2) on an [emachines G630](http://support.gateway.com/emachines/notebook/2011/eMachines/emg/eMG630/eMG630sp2.shtml) laptop are broken. It has no bluetooth and no expansion slots.

Is there a way to still connect an external keyboard & mouse?

I am not talking not working, as in missing drivers, I am talking broken off, ripped... :(

Comment: Buddy you are looking for a magic, right? If there is no USB port and Bluetooth is not available then you can't connect Keyboard and mouse in any way. Good way to just repair your USB ports or get the new one as they are no too costly.

Comment: I'm assuming you want input devices to save important files of a broken laptop? In that case you might want to shut down the laptop, remove the battery, open it up and take out the hard drive. Connect it to another computer and copy your files over.

Comment: No, i am trying to make a broken laptop functional... you are right, I guess it would be close to magic... i guess i was hoping for sometghing like ethernet to usb or something crazy... HAHA! as i see it there is only two options, replace the motherboard or replace the usb ports...

Comment: I guess i could use it like a server or something that only requires remote desktop...

Comment: If you want to put some files on it then you can use cloud space, upload it your any cloud space account and then download it on that laptop will be easy but cost you the bandwidth.

Comment: What’s wrong with just using the built-in keyboard and trackpad? ಠ_ఠ If it’s been damaged that badly, then you won’t want to use it as an everyday system; it’s best left as a backup system, in which case the internal ones are sufficient.

Comment: @Synetech it is unpractical in a desktop setting... it is not damaged that bad, in fact, the computer is functioning just fine, but the ports are ripped from stepping on usb cabels...

Comment: So they are not ripped *off* right? They are still there, but not connected (properly?) from being jiggled too much? In that case, your best bet is simply to have someone fix the broken solder joints.

Comment: Well, there is nothing in the ports, they are just holes with a couple of metal pins stikking out like spaggheti... HAHA :/

Comment: @DanielVallandTorgrimsen Pictures would be helpful in this case. Show everyone who's misunderstanding just how bad it is.

Comment: True... here is a picture: http://www.mediafire.com/?0rrrvqpwtbdpo0v

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at support.gateway.com."*

Answer (score 1):

Your netbook only has two USB 2.0 ports. With those broken off you can not connect an external keyboard to it, nor can you add a USB based BT dongle.

You still have a working Ethernet interface, so you can use another computer to access the eMachine (e.g. via SSH, X or RDP). However this is not quite the same as just using an external keyboard.

If you are creative you can remove [the netbooks internal keyboard](http://www.laptopkeyboard.com/Guides.php/eMachines/G%20Series/G630/KBAC30) and put that in a case. That would be fun to do, but probably not very practical.

Comment: `You still have a working Ethernet interface, so you can use another computer to access the eMachine (e.g. via SSH, X or RDP). However this is not quite the same as just using an external keyboard.`   Especially since it already has a built-in keyboard and trackpad; obviously they want to use it like a regular everyday, desktop in which case remote-control isn’t going to cut it.

Comment: True. Which is why I added the link to removing the internal keyboard. Fun to do, but not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Well you might find the USB ports on a docking station work fine even if the ones on the laptop itself do not work . My laptop works like this and I am using a USB keyboard connected to the docking station to type this message.

Comment: This appears to be a comment.  Comments belong in the comment section.  If you do not have the reputation to post a comment, it means, you should not be submitting comments at all. You should modify this answer, so it answers the proposed question, good questions are specific and extremely detailed